# ng-repeat in html table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am making an html table and I use this code:

```
<table>
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th colspan="2">The table header</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  <tr ng-repeat="item in myDynamicLabels">
                    <td> {{item}}</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr ng-repeat="value in myDynamicData track by $index" >
                       <td>{{value}}</td>
                   </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
```

The output i get is
item
item
item
value 
value
value

But i want it to be in columns so:
item  value
item  value
item  value

How can i fix this and still use ng-repeat?

```
   angular.forEach(data.results.bindings, function(val)
       {
           $scope.myDynamicLabels.push(val.state.value);
           $scope.myDynamicData.push(val.nbr_university.value);

       })
```

This is my javascript code for the labels and data

Comment: can you please put what type of data you have in myDynamicLabels and myDynamicData arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code like this:

```
 angular.forEach(data.results.bindings, function(val)
       {
           let jsonData = {
             state: val.state.value,
             university: val.nbr_university.value
           }
           $scope.myDynamicData.push(jsonData);

       })
```

And use ng-repeat something like this:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">The table header</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="value in myDynamicData track by $index" >
        <td>{{value.state}}</td>
        <td>{{value.university}}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this is what you are willing to do.

Answer (score 0):

If the labels are associated with the data, you can have a map with them and use item.label and item.value inside the same ng-repeat.

If you don't want a map, you need at least a way to get the value you want somehow getValueForLabel(item).

But in the end, there should be only one ng-repeat

Comment: angular.forEach(data.results.bindings, function(val)
       {
           $scope.myDynamicLabels.push(val.state.value);
           $scope.myDynamicData.push(val.nbr_university.value);
           
       })
This is how i defined label and data, how can i associate the labels with this data?